# Where's the bug in this simple std::list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I can't understand where's the problem with this very simple list I've been testing. The idea is to get the item at position i in a list.
I know usually I wouldn't use a list to do that. 
However, this works when I set `item = 11`, `item = 12` and `item = 13` (output would be, respectively, `at position {1, 2, 3} there's the item {11, 12, 13}`), BUT it does not work when I set `item = 10`, as the output is `at position 0 there's the item 6`.

```
int main(void)
{
    list<int> L;
    L.push_back(10);
    L.push_back(11);
    L.push_back(12);
    L.push_back(13);

    int item = 10;
    int pos;

    list<int>::iterator it = moveToItem(item, L, pos);

    cout << "at position " << pos << " there's the item " << *it;
}

list<int>::iterator moveToItem(int item, list<int> L, int& pos)
{
     pos = 0;
     list<int>::iterator it = L.begin();

     while(*it != item)
     {
         it++;
         pos++;
     }
     return it;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A copy of the list `L` is being made when `moveToItem()` is called so the returned iterator is referring to an item of a `list` that has been destructed. Pass the `list` by reference instead:

```
list<int>::iterator moveToItem(int item, list<int>& L, int& pos)
                                                //^
```

You should also protect against going past the `end()` of the `list` in the `while` condition, before dereferencing `it`.

If this is not an exercise consider using the STL algorithm [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [`std::distance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) instead:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::list<int>::iterator it = std::find(L.begin(), L.end(), 41);
if (it != L.end())
{
    std::cout << "at position "
              << std::distance(L.begin(), it)
              << " there's the item "
              << *it
              << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a reference to your list when calling the `list<int>::iterator moveToItem(int item, list<int> L, int& pos)` currently a copy of your list made.

So your method should be `list<int>::iterator moveToItem(int item, list<int>& L, int& pos)` instead. You can keep the body of your method the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the list by-value. Therefore the returned iterator is an iterator into the local `L` argument of the function and is therefore invalid once the function returned (and `L` got destroyed). You should take `L` by reference:

```
list<int>::iterator moveToItem(int item, list<int> &L, int& pos)
```

Performance-wise it's not the best idea to take such a possibly large datastructure as a list by-value, anyway.